# losing internet connection on windows 10 when an MS hyper-v external virtual switch is active

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

When I activate an external vswitch from hyperv, I lose internet connection until I de-activate it. I'm using windows 10.

configuration details here: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dtnWWU4OtvfLbvjbmA8v6Ws8_OeJ0YSFTRaiL7bSEhU/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried changing to DHCP, but no luck. I've tried changing security policy to make all networks private. I've tried manually setting a default gateway (wasn't sure what to input, though)

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the **VLAN ID** tagging in **Virtual Switch Configuration** since it doesn't look like you are using VLANs in your network.

[image]

That should fix the issue.